Filling a specific region in the original graphic
Hı
I have an excel-based chart file that I downloaded from a forex site.
I will give the download link below.
What I want is to apply fill to certain areas of the entire graphic, as I explained in the images.
Example

Link:forexpnf site
I wanted to define it as + and - through chartcol and chartcol definitions, but I could not succeed.
I don't have enough coding knowledge to do this.
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim ChartP As Worksheet
Dim RowNo As Integer
Dim ChartRow As Integer
Dim ChartCol As Integer
Dim ChartAxis As Integer
Dim ChartStart As Double
Dim Label As Double
Dim x As Integer
Dim BlockSize As Double
Dim Reversal As Double
Dim CurrentPrice As Double
Dim CurrentTrend As Integer   ' 1 = up 0 = down
Dim NewPrice As Double
Dim high As Double
Dim low As Double
Dim upcount As Double
Dim downcount As Double


Public Sub Calculate()
   Set Data = Worksheets("OHLCV")
   Set ChartP = Worksheets("Chart")
   'Clear any previous chart
   Range("E4:IV2114").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   
   BlockSize = ChartP.Cells(2, 5)
   Reversal = ChartP.Cells(3, 5)
   CurrentTrend = 1
   
   ' work out axis and labels
   x = 1
   high = 0
   low = 10000000
   Do While Data.Cells(x, 5) <> ""
      If Data.Cells(x, 3) > high Then high = Data.Cells(x, 3)
      If Data.Cells(x, 4) < low Then low = Data.Cells(x, 4)
      x = x + 1
   Loop
   upcount = ((high - Data.Cells(1, 3)) / BlockSize)
   downcount = ((Data.Cells(1, 3) - low) / BlockSize)
   
   
   ChartAxis = upcount + 8  ' row where chart starts
   ChartRow = ChartAxis
   ChartCol = 6
   'Label the chart axis's
   '30 points + and - the first number
   ChartStart = Data.Cells(1, 3)
   Data.Cells(ChartAxis, 5) = ChartStart
   For x = 1 To upcount + 1
      Label = ChartStart + (x * BlockSize)
      ChartP.Cells(ChartAxis - x, 5) = Label
      
   Next x
   For x = 1 To downcount + 1
      Label = ChartStart - (x * BlockSize)
      ChartP.Cells(ChartAxis + x, 5) = Label
      
   Next x
   x = 1
   CurrentPrice = ChartStart
   Do While Data.Cells(x, 5) <> ""
      If CurrentTrend = 1 Then   ' CurrentTrend = UP
         NewPrice = Data.Cells(x, 3)  ' days high
         If NewPrice >= CurrentPrice + BlockSize Then ' mark up
            Do While NewPrice >= CurrentPrice + BlockSize
               ChartRow = ChartRow - 1
               ChartP.Cells(ChartRow, ChartCol) = "X"
               CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice + BlockSize
            Loop
         Else ' look for a reversal
             NewPrice = Data.Cells(x, 4)  ' days low
             If NewPrice <= CurrentPrice - (BlockSize * Reversal) Then
               CurrentTrend = 0
               ChartCol = ChartCol + 1
               Do While NewPrice <= CurrentPrice - BlockSize
                  ChartRow = ChartRow + 1
                  ChartP.Cells(ChartRow, ChartCol) = "0"
                  CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice - BlockSize
               Loop
            End If
         End If
      
      Else   ' Current Trend = down
         NewPrice = Data.Cells(x, 4)  ' days low
         If NewPrice <= CurrentPrice - BlockSize Then
            Do While NewPrice <= CurrentPrice - BlockSize
               ChartRow = ChartRow + 1
               ChartP.Cells(ChartRow, ChartCol) = "0"
               CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice - BlockSize
            Loop
         Else   ' look for a reversal
            NewPrice = Data.Cells(x, 3)  ' days high
            If NewPrice >= CurrentPrice + (BlockSize * Reversal) Then
               CurrentTrend = 1
               ChartCol = ChartCol + 1
               Do While NewPrice >= CurrentPrice + BlockSize
                  ChartRow = ChartRow - 1
                  ChartP.Cells(ChartRow, ChartCol) = "X"
                  CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice + BlockSize
               Loop
            End If
          End If
       End If
      
      x = x + 1
   Loop
   
End Sub

Sub ClearData()
    Range("A1:B3000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub


In line 12749 shouldn't be marked the first O, and in line 12754 the first X. Fill means background color as on the image?

Each x and o column should be marked relative to the previous column.
Data is added all over the page and continuously.
For "x" this is a mark that is 1 more than the previous x peak.
The previous value for "o" is marked 1 lower than its base.

I mistype 12754. It is 12774. The question is the same. In line 12774 the first X is one row above 12769 line second X.

It should appear on the entire page.
The full order of the region I gave as an example is as follows:
12654="0"
12624="0"
12649="x"
12659="x"
12674="x"
12649="0"
12574="0"
12559="0"

and yes we have to show it with fill color

There might be such an idea. for "x": the box "x" with one surplus from the column "o" next to it is filled.for "o": the "o" box, which is one more than the "x" column next to it, is filled in. "x" is moving up and "o" is moving down.

This code produce the following result on a sheet
Sub plus_minus_color()
Set rang = Range("B4:O25") 'the range to check
'first or the last row of the sheet must not contains any data.
defcolor = rgbLightGreen ' the backcolor of the cell
firstcol = rang.Columns(1).Column
lastcol = rang.Columns(rang.Columns.Count).Column

If Cells(1, firstcol).End(xlDown) = "o" Then

For i = firstcol To lastcol - 2 Step 2
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)) Then
    Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i + 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2)) Then
    Cells(1, i + 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
Next i

Else

For i = firstcol To lastcol - 2 Step 2
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)) Then
    Cells(Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2)) Then
    Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
Next i

End If

End Sub



With two colors
Sub plus_minus_color()
Set rang = Range("B4:O25")
'first or the last row of the sheet must not contains any data.
defcolor = rgbLightGreen
defcolor2 = rgbRed
firstcol = rang.Columns(1).Column
lastcol = rang.Columns(rang.Columns.Count).Column
If Cells(1, firstcol).End(xlDown) = "o" Then
For i = firstcol To lastcol - 2 Step 2
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)) Then
    Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor2
  End If
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i + 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2)) Then
    Cells(1, i + 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
  
Next i
Else
For i = firstcol To lastcol - 2 Step 2
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2)) Then
    Cells(Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor2
  End If
  If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2)) Then
    Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Interior.Color = defcolor
  End If
  
Next i

End If
End Sub



I want to ask your opinion.
Is it possible to improve your codes for cases where x and 0 are in the same column?
Could you please look at the approach in the picture I gave in the link and share your opinion?      Link:  https://www.imghippo.com/i/itqkb1728987631.png

I am using the codes you recently edited, thank you.
Can we think of this as a different working and code system?

The simplest way (imho) to modify checking emptiness to equality of x or o respectively.

Your other question terminology not clear for me. Small mods does  not change working algorithm base. (if this is you are after about)

I think it is not possible to represent the figure I showed in the last link.
Am I understanding correctly?

Our current code works like this when x and 0 are in the same column.    https://www.imghippo.com/i/DRgFi1728993693.png

The actual code checks if there is any character in the position. Therefore should change IsEmpty commands to equality of character x or o, then it will color only when the condition is fulfilled.Try to make the recommended mod. and if you are stucked then post  a follow-up question of the specific issue where you need help.

SIDENOTE: In the case you described from where will you know that it is an x or o column? Or both? (then finding the highest and lowest characters is a task which must be added.

You are right, defining value will be challenging.
I will continue to use your initial work.
Thanks for the idea.
